# WSO2IS: Verifing user is already logged using ssoTokenId in an HTTP request

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have followed the steps [in this tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server) to retrieve a `ssoTokenID` in my HTTP response header from the WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0. I am running this locally.

To simulate a secondary App, I want to send a HTTP request to the WSO2 Identity Server, from a different browser. I would like to receive some kind of confirmation that the user is indeed logged in. Maybe a SAML response?

I assume the following:

- It is not relevant to add the JSESSIONID
- It is not possible to reuse a SAML assertion received in the first app

I would expect to send the following request to the demo app, or the WSO2 Identity Server to get this confirmation. Unfortunately this does not work. What is the proper way to confirm that the user is already logged in?

```
http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/home.jsp?ssoTokenId=5851787BC6FA951FE3A5776BE83F9B03
```

or

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp?ssoTokenId=1E5F811E2FAC8AFBEE31621E889DE3FD
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, Assuming that the user is logged in via SSO,If the user attempts to perform a single signon from a new tab of a browser the user is already logged into via SSO, he or she will be directed directly to the system without having to log into the system.However, if its a new browser then, the system identifies and treats this as a separate session and requires the user to enter the login credentials.

Regards,Shavantha